# can anyone help identify the chop mark please and translate (Characters identified: 一切惟心艁)

Tags: character-identification, seal

[image]

I have a beautiful scroll given to me and am trying to find out the history of the seal

Answer (score 3):

well, again, read from right to left, top to bottom. and, don’t fixated on regular script (楷書)

the top right character [“一”](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E4%B8%80), and the top left character [“心”](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%BF%83) (in small seal script) are easy to recognise.

Next, the bottom right character, the left component is also a “心”, and I recognised the right component is [“隹”](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E9%9A%B9) (a bird); which made it [“惟”](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%83%9F).

So, the text is “一x惟心x”.

I known the verse “一切惟心”, a buddhism notion, I would guess the middle right character is [“切”](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%88%87). See the link as proof.

The last one, the bottom left character, again, I recognised the right component [“告”](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%91%8A).

At this moment, my “free association” of it is “一切惟心造”, however, the right component did not like a “⻍“, or a “辵“ (radical 162)

The next inference is: it might be a variant (異體字). So, I would try these two sites, search for variants of “造”:

- https://chardb.iis.sinica.edu.tw/variants.jsp?cid=23691
- https://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/variants/rbt/word_attribute.rbt?quote_code=QTA0MTQ2

Voilà, the left component might be [“舟”](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E8%88%9F)

Last, when the text is found to be “一切惟心艁”, I just google it as “一切惟心造”, and pick a simple, acceptable result, and interpret it in English.

“一切惟心艁” might be interpreted differently, according to the sect. Any further elaboration would be better asked in buddhism forum, imo.

have fun :)

Comment: Something like what Johann Goethe said , "Man is made by his belief. As he believes so he is" The Buddhist has a metaphysical concept that everything, including your own innate psychological make-up, even the Universe itself, is a product of one's mind -- "you think so you become...."

Answer (score 0):

I think it meant to say "[一切唯心造](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%80%E5%88%87%E5%94%AF%E5%BF%83%E9%80%A0)" - "Everything is created by your mind".